# can't delete data from table using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to delete data from table `student` and also on `library` but i can't delete data from table because foreign key is assigned to library table

```
DELETE student, library 
FROM student INNER JOIN library 
ON student.id = library.student_id 
WHERE student.id=6
```

and also there is error showing:

```
 1. Unexpected keyword. (near "INNER JOIN" at position 37) 
 2. Unrecognized statement type. (near "INNER JOIN" at position 37)
```

Comment: Is student and library is columns

Comment: Is your db really `MySQL`?

Comment: Please run `SELECT @@version;` and show us what RDBMS product you are using (that statement will work in both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete data from multiple tables with single query at a time and join can be used for complex comparisons. Such as if you want to delete students records which are in the particular `address` and exist in the `library` table. In your case, if you go with individual queries with join then it will delete all the data where `id=6` from both the tables so

```
DELETE s
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN library l ON s.id = l.student_id 
WHERE s.id = 6
```

is equivalent to

```
DELETE FROM students WHERE id = 6  --if this id exist in library table
```

If you have constraing with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it will delete data from `library` table as well

```
DELETE FROM students WHERE id = 6
```

if you don't have, then use individual queries for both table data's

to delete child records first then master records

```
DELETE FROM library WHERE student_id = 6
DELETE FROM students WHERE id = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Joins take data from multiple tables and concatenates it into one result set. `DELETE` deletes rows, not result sets - you need to identify specific rows from specific tables, hence it doesn't make much sense to make joins in a `DELETE`.

The normal ways of dealing with removing related data from other tables are either doing multiple `DELETE` statements, or having `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in place and relying on `ON DELETE CASCADE`. See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for details.

Comment: Nope, MySQL support `delete join` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html.

Comment: To be fair, MySQL supporting something doesn't necessarily mean it makes sense or is a good idea :)

Comment: @jlaitio, multi-table UPDATE and DELETE are *very* good ideas. It's a shame these features don't exist in the SQL spec. Microsoft SQL Server supports multi-table UPDATE, but with slightly different syntax from MySQL. Microsoft does not support multi-table DELETE, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link as reference

**http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/**

Answer (score 0):

The core purpose of JOINs are to retrieve data. You can also use DELETE with JOINS, but you can delete from only one table at a time.

In simple way, you can achieve this using this query:

```
DELETE
FROM student
WHERE  id=1

DELETE
FROM library
WHERE student_id =1
```

Or, you can use the Cascading Referential integrity. By Setting the Cascading referential Integrity, you defines what to happen when a row which referenced by a Foreign key has been deleted or updated.
For more Details about Cascading referential integrity watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETepOVi7Xk8